# Error installing react-native-firebase/storage......."`@react-native-firebase/app/lib.common does not exist in the Haste module map`"

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I installed package "react-native-firebase/storage" as per git instructions (`npm install @react-native-firebase/storage --save`)

Then I imported package with "`import rnFb from '@react-native-firebase/storage'`";

However its giving me the error "`@react-native-firebase/app/lib.common does not exist in the Haste module map`"

Ive tried the instructions given on error message..but to no avail

```
1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

UPDATE 11/20
@react-native-firebase/storage folder in present in node_modules folder....however "app" folder is not (which is what the error appears to be complaining about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i believe is you havent downloaded the @react-native-firebase/app which is a pre-requisite to dwonload . Try downloading [App firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app) first , and then try. Hope it helps. Otherwise feel free to ask any doubts

[image: Storage]

Answer (score 2):

`cd` into your project directory.
Install `app` package first by, 
`yarn add @react-native-firebase/app` 
Then install storage package by `yarn add @react-native-firebase/storage`.
Then execute `yarn install` and the installed packages will be linked to the project.

You can verify the installation by checking `package.json` file. Dependencies in `package.json` should be as follows.

`"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.0.4",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10"
  },`